# Overflow : I just want to know how the computers correct the overflow

Tags: c, overflow

I built these codes and knew that overflows didn't affect the next address (= ptr + 1).

```
void main(void)
{
    unsigned short int over = 0;
    unsigned short int *ptr = &over;
    printf("%x", over);
    over = 0xffff0fff;

    printf("%x", *(ptr + 1));
}
```

so, I just want to know how the computers correct the overflows.
I thought the CPU cut the overflowed bits. Is that right?
If it is, please tell me how the CPU cut the overflowed bits.
Thanks :)

Comment: 0xffff0fff is 32 bit integer, and the answer may vary.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct the overflow"?  You aren't doing any arithmetic on your integer, so there is no opportunity for overflow.

Comment: If you're expecting to find the overflowing bits at the next address, well ... that's not the case. The value you're writing is just truncated to fit. As the warning you're getting says: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]

Comment: `printf("%x", *(ptr + 1));` is UB.  Code is accessing memory with an address `ptr + 1` that may not be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow is an error that occurs when you perform some operations on some data after which it exceeds the allocated size. For example:

```
char a[] = {0xFF, 0x00};
a[0] = a[0] + 0x02;
```

Here I allocated a block of memory of 2 bytes (char is usually 1 byte). In the first byte I placed the value 0xFF and in the second one, 0x00. On the second line I perform the addition 0xFF + 0x02, whose result is 0x101. It requires at least 9 bytes to be represented, and I assign it to a variable which has only 8 bits available. So, the first bit is dropped and a[0] will have the value 0x01. Of course, a[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) will still be 0x00.

So, the overflow isn't corrected. The value of a[0] is wrong, due to the overflow. But it's effects are limited (a[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) isn't affected). This is all that an overflow means. Some bits are dropped and the value is corrupted.

There is another kind of overflow, that does not involve any truncation. Most signed data types use [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). I will over simplify this and I will say that the most significant bit acts as a sign-bit: for the negative numbers it's 1 and for the positive ones, it's 0. For a signed char, the highest positive number you can have is 0x7F (127). If you add 0x01 to it, you will get 0x80. There has been no truncation, but, due to overflow, it's value is -128.

Speaking about your code:

- You didn't assign a value to *(ptr+1), so there is garbage and you can't tell if it has been affected or not.
- Your value is just truncated. This is pretty easy to spot, the problem is when the overflow occurs in the middle of some computations.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow mean assigning the data beyond the range it can hold. It is generally defined as `undefined behaviour` 
 I can give you an example as

`unsigned char c=300;//unsigned char can hold up only upto 255,this assignment is called overflow.`

overflow is represented in C by assigning random value to it in range of that data type.
 Example

```
unsigned char c=300;//will assign c with a value between 0 to 255 randomly
char c=300;//will assign c with a value between -127 to 128 randomly
```

This is similar to int,float any datatype.

**I just want to know how the computers correct the overflow** 
- probably you by now understsood how overflow is treated.
 If char is overflowed its value will be undefined and will be in same memory allocated to it example 1 BYTE.Overflow doesnot mean its value will occupy memory location adjacent to it.The value will be set in the memory allocated to it by its datatype.